# CakePHP isAuthorized not working properley when passing arguments

Tags: php, cakephp, authorization, cakephp-2.0

I'm using `isAuthorized` to deny access to methods if the record id doesn't belong to the user.  Profiles can have many documents and documents belong to one profile:

Controller/DocumentsController.php

```
public function add($id = null) {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->request->data['Document']['profile_id'] = $id;
        $this->request->data['Document']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
        $this->Document->create();
        if ($this->Document->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The document has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The document could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
}

public function isAuthorized($user) {
    if ($this->action === 'index') {
        return true;
    }

    if (in_array($this->action, array('view', 'add', 'edit', 'delete'))) {
        $document_id = $this->request->params['pass'][0];
        if ($this->Document->isOwnedBy($document_id, $user['id'])) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return parent::isAuthorized($this->Auth->user());
}
```

Model/Document.php

```
public function isOwnedBy($document, $user) {
    return $this->field('id', array('id' => $document, 'user_id' => $user)) === $document;
}
```

I'm passing the `profile id` as `$id` to `docments/add` from one of my profile views via Cake link helper:

View/Profiles/view.ctp

```
echo $this->Html->link('New Document',
    array('controller' => 'documents', 'action' => 'add',$profile['Profile']['id'])
);
```

What happens when I click on New Document from `profiles/view` is that it sends the request but doesn't redirect, just refreshes the page, or it redirects back to `profiles/view`, not sure which.  My first guess is since I'm not defining the `profile id` in the `isAuthorized` callback within `DocumentsController`, `isOwnedBy` is returning false.  Any suggestions on how to get the profile id in `isAuthorized` within `DocumentsController`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you do a bit more testing/debugging to determine whether or not it's even getting into `isAuthorized` and if so, where it's failing...etc?

Comment: It is, when I add the add methdod to the list of allowed actions, I can add documents no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is relativley easy.  When using isAuthorized with parameters from another controller, be sure to reference the right model.

```
if ($this->Document->Profile->isOwnedBy($document_id, $user['id'])) {
    return true;
}
```